# jquery getJSON function timing issue

Tags: jquery, json, timing

I think my program is skipping result of JSON call.
Is it possible to make a closure function here or make the program wait for JSON call to return?

```
function username_not_duplicate(username) {
   var function_name = "get_username";
   var parameters = [username];
   var url = "/get_functions.php?function_name=" + function_name + "&parameters=" + parameters;
   $.getJSON(url, function(user_name) {
      if (user_name == true) {     
         return true;
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

Comment: You want the username_not_duplicate function to wait until the getJSON call finishes?

Comment: need to see get_functions.php. meanwhile, use firebug to monitor what's being returned to ensure it's a bare boolean, which i doubt, altho you are using the return as if it is

Answer (score 13):

The `$.getJSON()` API call is asynchronous.  You can make it synchronous by using `$.ajax()` this way:

```
function username_not_duplicate(username) {
   var function_name = "get_username";
   var parameters = [username];
   var url = "/get_functions.php?function_name=" + function_name + "&parameters=" + parameters;
   var rslt = false;
   $.ajax({
     async: false,
     url: url,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       if (data == true) {     
         rslt = true;
       }
     }
   });
   return rslt;
}
```

Comment: A key part of this for me was the var rslt = false;  I was trying to return true/false from inside the success: which was not returning a bool from the function.

Answer (score 3):

Drew's answer is nearly perfect, just missing one bracket and comma for IE.

```
function username_not_duplicate(username) {
   var function_name = "get_username"; 
   var parameters = [username]; 
   var url = "camps/includes/get_functions.php?function_name=" + function_name + "&parameters=" + parameters;
   var rslt = false; 
   $.ajax({ 
         async: false, 
         url: url, 
         dataType: "json", 
         success: function(data) {
           if (data == true) {                   
             rslt = true; 
           }
        }, 
    });
    return rslt; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another choice is to use a call back function and pass it to the function that executes the getJSON as:

```
//this is the function that executes my getJSON
//callback is the name of my callback function
function getMyData( callback ){

  //here you do your getJSON call
  $.getJSON(url, function(items){

    //do your stuff here

    //call your function here (at the end)
    callback();

  });

}
```

This way your callback function will be called at the end of the getJSON call.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, `username_not_duplicate` just returns `false` immediately because `getJSON` is asynchronous (ie non-blocking). The `return true` statement just returns `true` from the response handler.
Normally, you shouldn't do such a blocking calls you're trying to achieve. I suppose you can consider remembering of a state of the request somewhere globally.

Comment: can i make getJSON non synchronous?

Comment: @bob -- nope.  Would be a good option for jQuery to add though.

Comment: @bob `$.getJSON` is a simply shorthand of an equivalent `$.ajax` function, which allows to send synchronous requests. See `async` setting at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . So... the answer is 'yes, not `$.getJSON` but `$.ajax`'