# jQuery text() inside .getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get names from a Pokemon API and putting it into a div field in html, but the .text() function from jQuery doesn't seem to place the text into the html when I put it inside a .getJSON function. Just curious what could this problem be? Thanks.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="1">
            <div id="name1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="2">
            <div id="name2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="3">
            <div id="name3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="4">
            <div id="name4"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*Works*/
for(var j = 1; j < 5; j++){
    $("#name" + j).text("HELLO");
}
/*Doesn't work*/
for(var j = 1; j < 5; j++){
    var webAddress2 = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + j;
    $.getJSON(webAddress2, function(data) {
        console.log("test");
        $("#name" + j).text("SOME TEXT");
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Try answer on this  post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347750/getjson-and-for-loop-issue

Answer (score 1):

Since the `getJSON` is asynchronous at the time of success function is executes value of `j` would be `5`. There is no element with id `name5` so nothing would happen. To make it work use **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*Works*/
  for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    $("#name" + j).text("HELLO");
  }
  /*Doesn't work*/
  for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    var webAddress2 = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + j;
    (function(j) {
      $.getJSON(webAddress2, function(data) {
        console.log("test");
        $("#name" + j).text("SOME TEXT");
      });
    })(j);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="1">
      <div id="name1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="2">
      <div id="name2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="3">
      <div id="name3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="4">
      <div id="name4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or using **[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** for block level scope variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*Works*/
  for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    $("#name" + j).text("HELLO");
  }
  /*Doesn't work*/
  for (let j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    var webAddress2 = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + j;
    $.getJSON(webAddress2, function(data) {
      console.log("test");
      $("#name" + j).text("SOME TEXT");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="1">
      <div id="name1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="2">
      <div id="name2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="3">
      <div id="name3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="4">
      <div id="name4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @jayzhou :  glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Create a closure inside the loop. Since `getJSON` is an asynchronous ,operation, loop will finish it's execution without waiting for `getJSON` to finish it's each execution.

You need to bind the value of `j` with the closure

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    (function(index) {
      var webAddress2 = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + index;
      $.getJSON(webAddress2, function(data) {
        console.log("test");
        $("#name" + index).text("SOME TEXT");
      });
    }(j))
  }
});
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your help! It looks like I got a lot to learn about Javascript.