# getJSON block nested in a for loop only executes in the last iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {     //Make a call to an api with the a url. 

    // Take the Response field of the json response. 
    // This field contains objects
    var d = data['Response'];             

    for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {     // For each object
        var obj1 = d[i];                    
        var id = obj1['id'];            // Take the id of the object

        var url2 = endpoint+'id='+id                     

        // Make a new api call based on the id of the object
        $.getJSON(url2, function(obj2) {
            console.log(i)
        });
    }
});
```

For some reason, this prints only the last value of `i`. Although, when I print the values of `i` outside the inner block and inside the `for` block it prints all the values of `i`.

I also tried to use `let` instead of `var` for `i` but it prints values of `i` randomly and not sequentialy. It also prints some values twice.

Why is this happening?
How can I make the inner block print all the values the `i` takes during the for loop?

Comment: Did you checked this similar question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347750/getjson-and-for-loop-issue

Comment: @BJohn Yes and I tried the solution with the ```let``` as I mention in the post but that prints values of ```i``` randomly and not sequentialy.

Comment: That's probably because `getJSON` is async. You might want to refactor to accumulate the data in a top-level object (keyed by index) rather than outputting it immediately.

Comment: Read more: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-make-loop-of-getjson-calls-wait-for-each-other/134745/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is classical problem when callback is called ,as mentioned in the 
similar question did you try to put the anonymous function inside your loop ?
instead of using let ?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {     //Make a call to an api with the a url. 
        var d = data['Response'];             //Take the Response field of the json response. This field contains objects

        for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {     //For each object
          (function(i) { // protects i in an immediately called function 
          var obj1 = d[i];                    
            var id = obj1['id'];            //Take the id of the object

            var url2 = endpoint+'id='+id
            $.getJSON(url2, function(obj2) {                     //Make a new api call based on the id of the object
                console.log(i)
              });
           })(i);
        }
```

});