# getJSON() call is not executed inside a keypress event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying implement a search box functionality and whenever user presses enter I am calling `$.getJSON` to query my web service. The problem is I can see that my keypress is handler is called but it never executes `$.getJSON()`.

EDIT: I debugged further using Fiddler. I can see that request is going out and I get a HTTP 200 response. Now I am surprised why the remaining part of code is not executed.

What could be the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#searchUser").keypress(function (event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
                if(keycode == '13'){
                    var queryString = this.value;
                    $.getJSON("/api/users", function(result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            result = sortJSON(result, 'name');
                            var html = '<tbody>';
                            var i = 0;
                            for ( i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                var j = 0;
                                var groups = '';

                                html += '<tr>';
                                html += '<td>' + result[i].id + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>' + result[i].emailAddress + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>' + result[i].name + '</td>';

                                result[i].groups = sortJSON(result[i].groups, 'name');
                                for ( j = 0; j < result[i].groups.length; j++) {
                                    groups += result[i].groups[j].name + ", ";
                                }

                                html += '<td>' + groups + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>' + result[i].department.name + '</td>';
                                html += '<td>SK</td>';
                                html += '</tr>';
                            }
                            html += '</tbody>';
                            $('#dataTable').append(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
```

});

Comment: How do you know for sure it's being called?

Comment: And how do you know for sure that `$.getJSON()` isn't executing?

Comment: For the millionth time, just use `event.which`. jQuery normalizes the retrieval of the key code into `e.which` so you don't have to do `(event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);`

Comment: @StephenThomas I kept a breakpoint and saw that $.getJSON() call is never executed.

Comment: is the input inside a form?  what's the point of `var queryString = this.value;` if you never use it?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ input is not inside a form. `var queryString = this.value;` I forgot remove this variable

Comment: are you sure no errors are occuring? you have no .error() handler, it might be executing but there is probably an error coming from the server

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I debugged further using Fiddler. I can see that request is going out and I get a HTTP 200 response. Now I am surprised why the remaining part of code is not executed.

Comment: *"Now I am surprised why the remaining part of code is not executed."* most likely because the request is not returning valid json, resulting in the error handler being triggered instead.

Comment: Does fiddler show what is inside the response?  If not, do you have Chrome?  Check the network tab and see if the response is returning anything ie. your JSON..  does your console show any errors?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ FIddler and Chrome network tab shows valid JSON response.

Comment: have you tried doing a console.log(result) in the success function?  maybe try it before the if check.  Also try to see if it gets inside the if check.  Most importantly.. does your console show any errors?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I think I figured out the problem. When .getJSON() is called chrome network tab shows the response is pending. Since $.getJSON() call is asynchronous, I had to use $.ajax() call and set async: false. Looks like my problem is resolved.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419026/jquery-getjson-function-timing-issue

Comment: Only thing is that making the ajax call synchronous will lock up your browser until the call finishes.. It's not a good idea to do that.  Your code should work fine as asynchronous because everything is inside your success function - which waits for the 200 response to return before executing.  There must be something else that's causing the error